# How to add route for and handle domain.com/?latest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to handle the following url's: (1) domain.com, (2) domain.com/?latest

This is what I think should be it...

**Global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeIndex", // Route name
    "/?{sortBy}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", sortBy = UrlParemeter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortBy) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
        // display stuff in a way that's sorted
    else
        // just display stuff by default
    return View( ... );
}
```

Issue: mvc doesn't like the route starting with hard-coded "?", but!, if don't map a route at all and just look for request.querystring["latest"], it comes up as null.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

**------- Edit:**

I know that I shouldn't use just /?latest and I should instead use /?sortBy=latest , but, it's a shorter url!!!1 and easier to type :)  I see that Google uses it sometimes, and I want to be like Google ;)

Setting aside the fact that it's not the best way to do it, is there a way to do /?latest ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query string is incomplete. Try this: domain.com/?sortBy=latest. You can remove the extra route mapping as well and use the default routing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need sortBy in your route definition. Just make sure the action method has an argument with the same name.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeIndex", // Route name
    "", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

And yes, in your route the part `?latest` is not okay. It should always be in the form `?varname=varvalue`.

Comment: but I see google doing that!  it's easier to type :)  I'm trying to avoid doing the ?key=value , to keep the url shorter.  is it possible tho?? thanks!

Comment: Then you might try checking whether the query string contains 'latest': Request.QueryString.Contains("latest") (or starts with).